# Upload content to S3 through CloudFront

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on an app which requires to upload images to S3. Now I am doing like this:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:nameOfThePicture inBucket:nameOfTheBucket];
    por.contentType = @"image/jpg";
    por.data        = imageData;

    // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
    S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];
    por.delegate = self;
```

Uploading an image directly to S3 is too slow and I have configured the CloudFront service. **Now, I'd like to upload an image through CloudFront to the origin bucket in S3. Is possible to do it? If yes, how could I do it?**

Really thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. CloudFront is a one-way affair — you can retrieve objects from S3 through CloudFront, but you cannot upload objects to S3 through CloudFront.

Comment: UPDATE: This changed October 2013.  CloudFront will now pass HTTP PUT and POST commands (among others) through to the origin.  AFAICT this does not work via the S3 API in any of the SDKs yet though.

Comment: I imagine that getting all of the S3 authorization headers to pass through correctly could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement in my project. Although I myself could not figure out everything, there is a link I came across.

http://raamdev.com/2008/using-curl-to-upload-files-via-post-to-amazon-s3/

I tried to mimic the same with PHP curl, but somehow I see that the key is uploaded, rather than image file. May be this code will provide you pointers, if anybody is able to figure out issue in the below script, it will be great help for me as well as anybody wanting to achieve this.

```
$url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/'; // cloudfront distribution url.

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("key"=>$_REQUEST['key'],"file"=>$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));


//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("key"=>$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (false == $result) {
    echo "Error while loading page: ", curl_error($ch), "\n"; 
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```