# Uploads to S3 through CloudFront via Signed URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have CloudFront using an S3 origin. I'd like to be able to generate signed URLs for uploading values into S3, if possible through the CloudFront distribution.

I've been poring over the docs but I haven't found anything on this. I'd imagine that as long as the query parameters are passed along, but is this the case?

[Not a duplicate of this: I'm using signed URLs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559203/upload-content-to-s3-through-cloudfront)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Presigned S3 URLs with Cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393685/presigned-s3-urls-with-cloudfront)

Answer (score 5):

Is the reason is to provide low latency access to user uploading files to a central bucket, from all around the world ?  In that case, I would recommend using S3 Transfer Acceleration instead.

> You might want to use Transfer Acceleration on a bucket for various
>   reasons, including the following:
>
> - You have customers that upload to a centralized bucket from all over the world.
> - You transfer gigabytes to terabytes of data on a regular basis across continents.
> - You are unable to utilize all of your available bandwidth over the Internet when uploading to Amazon S3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

Amazon S3 transfer acceleration *is* using Cloudfront under the scene.

> Transfer Acceleration takes advantage of Amazon CloudFront’s globally
>   distributed edge locations. As the data arrives at an edge location,
>   data is routed to Amazon S3 over an optimized network path.

Comment: I have an entirely serverless application. My S3 bucket name is long and unwieldy. Lambda generates a pre-signed URL for clients needing to upload files, that same Lambda receives S3 events and processes the file, moving it. So my goal would be that instead of returning the long bucket name, use the CloudFront domain to keep everything unified.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a CloudFront distribution to ingest S3 file uploads.

Depending on your setup, S3 Transfer Acceleration [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55148734/1081234) may still be a better option, it's certainly better documented and has more implementation examples!

### Create a new CF distribution

- Use target S3 bucket as origin
- Configure origin S3 bucket access to use a CloudFront origin access identity. While you can automatically update the bucket policy (with `s3:GetObject` access) as a starting point, we'll be adding/changing that to `s3:PutObject` anyway.

> [image: Configure S3 bucket access to use a CloudFront origin access identity]

- Configure "Allowed HTTP methods" to include `POST`

> [image: Configure allowed HTTP methods]

- We'll be allowing writing to the bucket, so it would be a good idea to "Restrict viewer access" and require CloudFront [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) or signed cookies for access.

> [image: Require signed URLs or cookies]

### Configure S3 bucket policy

- If you've started with an automatically updated bucket policy above, your bucket policy should contain something like below, where `XXXXX` is the OAI ID and `YOUR-TARGET-BUCKET` is, well, your target bucket:

```
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-TARGET-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- You can *add* `s3:PutObject` as an allowed action, but if you're setting up the distribution for content ingestion only (i.e. delivered through another distribution, or not publicly available at all) you could just replace the allowed action:

```
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
```

### Upload files to S3 using the CloudFront distribution

Once the distribution is updated, you would be able to add files to your bucket by making a `PUT` request to `https://your-distribution-url/desired-s3-key-name` using Postman or something. Remember to use a signed url here if that's what you've configured.

Your client connections to the CF edge should be consistently faster, while anecdotally S3 acceleration [speed comparison](http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html) isn't always favorable.

If I understand AWS pricing correctly, you will be charged for "[Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/)" ($0.02-$0.16/GB depending on region) compared with [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) charges ($0.04-$0.08/GB depending on region.)

Comment: Hi @Oleg thanks for this answer. 
CORS is blocking me to upload the file to S3 via signed CloudFront URL. 

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled"

Not sure how to configure this one. Is it S3 or CloudFront?

S3 allows access only to CF via IOA - it is safe then to "disable" CORS on S3?

Comment: Or should CORS allow access only from the CF by specifying CF's domain?

Comment: Hmm I'm no longer sure what went through my mind @Hola; is CORS something that can be easily handled with CF functions manipulating headers?

Comment: If I want to use Cloudfront both for reading and writing, can I restrict the allowed HTTP method using presigned URLs?

I would want to issue signed URLs that are only allowed for reading (GET) and some that are only allowed for uploading (PUT).

Comment: @Hola did you ever figure out the issue? I'm running into the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd imagine that as long as the query parameters are passed along, but is this the case?

Not quite.  CloudFront can be configured to pass through the query string parameters, but it still won't support this use case, because CloudFront injects an `X-Amz-Cf-Id` header into the request that it sends to S3.  Because the header starts with `X-Amz-*`, S3 requires it to be signed... but this is impossible, since you have no way of knowing its value.

A CloudFront origin access identity can be given permission to write to a bucket, but this is also messy, because then any path CloudFront can read from can also be written to -- CloudFront signed URLs allow "access" -- whatever kind of access CloudFront itself has -- and can't be configured as read-only, if CloudFront, via the OAI, is allowed to write to the bucket.

Transfer Acceleration is a better solution since it uses the CloudFront network for transport, but understands native S3 signed URLs.  Your argument related to wanting to use the domain name rather than the bucket name in the Lambda function signing the URLs breaks down... because you can't sign an S3 URL in any event, without actually knowing the bucket name.